# multiple tasks in android service

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to launch an activity from bound service on every successful bind. My activity (this remains same for for every bind request received) should get launched in a different task. I would like to retains all the tasks untill the unbind is called on all recieved requests.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onBind()` method of the service, you could do a `startService()` with the `Intent` for the activity, which has the `ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag set.

But if you want to be very sure of a succesfull bind, then I guess you could do it only from within `ServiceConnection`'s `onServiceConnected()` method. I don't know of a way where the service can know about a successfull bind.

Comment: so every time I start a new activity with FLAG_NEW_TASK set, it never starts new tasks same activity is presented back to me

Comment: Make sure you don't have any `launchMode` set to the activity in the manifest?